# JavaScript - How to prevent multiple operator inputs? (addition & subtraction)

Tags: javascript, input, calculator, operator-keyword

How do you prevent inputs of more than one operator?

Like to add validation if I press + it will show operation and if I press - since the last character is + should replace it.

And if the last character is + then I press + again, it should not append another plus like ++.

Here is the code:

```js
function ins(val) {
    document.getElementById("txtField").value += val
}

function clr() {
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = ""
}

function solve() {
    let x = document.getElementById("txtField").value
    let y = eval(x)
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = y
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add & Sub by CJ</h2>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" readonly>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="ins('1')">
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="ins('2')">
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="ins('3')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="ins('4')">
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="ins('5')">
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="ins('6')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="ins('7')">
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="ins('8')">
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="ins('9')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="ins('0')">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="ins('-')">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="ins('+')">
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clr()">
        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()">

        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can try this:)

```js
function ins(val) {
    let str = document.getElementById("txtField").value;
    let size = document.getElementById("txtField").value.length-1;
    if(val!=='+'&&val!=='-'){
       document.getElementById("txtField").value += val
    }else{
      if(size>-1){
        if(document.getElementById("txtField").value.charAt(size)!=='+' && document.getElementById("txtField").value.charAt(size)!=='-'){
          document.getElementById("txtField").value += val
        }else {
          if(val==='-'){
            if(document.getElementById("txtField").value.charAt(size)==='+'){
              document.getElementById("txtField").value=str.substring(0,size)+val
            }
          }else{
            if(document.getElementById("txtField").value.charAt(size)==='-'){
              document.getElementById("txtField").value=str.substring(0,size)+val
            }
          }
        }  
      }
    }
}

function clr() {
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = ""
}

function solve() {
    let x = document.getElementById("txtField").value
    let y = eval(x)
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = y
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add & Sub by CJ</h2>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" readonly>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="ins('1')">
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="ins('2')">
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="ins('3')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="ins('4')">
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="ins('5')">
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="ins('6')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="ins('7')">
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="ins('8')">
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="ins('9')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="ins('0')">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="ins('-')">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="ins('+')">
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clr()">
        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()">

        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that. Check it out.

what we've done here is: we first check if the value to be appended is an operator and if the last character in the display input is also an operator. Then if both conditions are met, we return without appending the new operator. This will prevent users from entering more than one operator in a row.

```js
function ins(val) {
    const InputValue = document.getElementById("txtField");
        const operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
        const lastChar = InputValue.value.slice(-1);
        var newText = InputValue.value + val;

        if (operators.includes(val) && operators.includes(lastChar)) {
          return;
        }
        InputValue.value = newText;
      }


function clr() {
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = ""
}

function solve() {
    let x = document.getElementById("txtField").value
    let y = eval(x)
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = y
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add & Sub by CJ</h2>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" readonly>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="ins('1')">
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="ins('2')">
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="ins('3')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="ins('4')">
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="ins('5')">
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="ins('6')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="ins('7')">
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="ins('8')">
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="ins('9')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="ins('0')">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="ins('-')">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="ins('+')">
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clr()">
        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()">

        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code please check now it will work according to your requirements. Happy coding !

```js
var i=-1;var j=-1;

function ins(val) {
      i=-1;
      j=-1;
   var str= document.getElementById("txtField").value += val;
   
    
}

function minsins(val) {
      j++
      if(j==0){
       var str= document.getElementById("txtField").value += val;
      }
  
   
    
}
function plusins(val) {
      i++
   if(i==0){
       var str= document.getElementById("txtField").value += val;
      }
  
    
}

function clr() {
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = ""
}

function solve() {
    let x = document.getElementById("txtField").value
    let y = eval(x)
    document.getElementById("txtField").value = y
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Add & Sub by CJ</h2>
        <input type="text" id="txtField" readonly>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="ins('1')">
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="ins('2')">
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="ins('3')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="ins('4')">
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="ins('5')">
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="ins('6')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="ins('7')">
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="ins('8')">
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="ins('9')">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="ins('0')">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="minsins('-')">
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="plusins('+')">
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clr()">
        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()">

        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```